# Login using Facebook-PHP-SDK

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

Very new to php and I am trying to figure out how to use Facebook-PHP-SDK. I set up an account on Facebook Developers and am trying to get data from my own Facebook, which I have linked to my developer account.  I am trying to implement the following practice code but I am confused about the login URL.  Am I suppose to put my own Facebook URL for that?  Or something else?

Practice Code

```
session_start();
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{app-id}', // Replace {app-id} with your app id
  'app_secret' => '{app-secret}',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v3.3',
  ]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

$permissions = ['email']; // Optional permissions
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://example.com/fb-callback.php', $permissions);

echo '<a href="' . htmlspecialchars($loginUrl) . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
```

Comment: Yes, this is what you suppose to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put in the login url the link of the file content your code:
example, this mean the file who contains the current code:

```
$loginUrl = "http://localhost/login.php"
```

and the https://example.com/fb-callback.php must redirect to a (file/url) in your application to verify the authentication and extract the access token for example.